# Please don't vent frustration by going against the rules

Tags: discussion

This question should be closed as story based:

[How to give a rationality-inducing drug to an entire software company?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/157741/21222)

It seems to be a jab at SE for "firing" one of the site's moderators, Monica Cellio. While I understand that SE's actions caused grief, one mistake does not justify another. Please do not subvert the site rules - if that question was an act of protest, then it was a shallow one.

Comment: I'm the person who wrote the question, and I'd like to apologize.  It was shallow, a bad idea, and I'm going to leave it closed.

Comment: @Gryphon I understand the feeling and in another context I might have been the one to open a question like that.

Comment: @Gryphon No worries, I can't claim to have never done anything...ill advised when annoyed/angry.

Comment: Which rule is that question exactly breaking? I didn't saw any rule breaking here, so I'd voted for a reopen. Criticism to SE parodying and satirizing it is ok, as long as it shows no disrespect nor spread false accusations or false information.

Comment: @VictorStafusa it's story based. That's the close reason.

Comment: @Mazura The post was ill-advised, but it was certainly not intended to incite violence.  I hadn't even seen that it could be interpreted that way until you pointed it out here.

Comment: If it's story based, which criteria for establishing it is story based applies?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have closed the question linked.

**I appreciate that people are upset and frustrated with what has happened but this isn't constructive.**

The question isn't all that bad. If it is edited to not be a jab at SE it can be reopened as far as I am concerned.

Going back on strike now.

Comment: I didn't read it through when first posted and up until the obvious jab at "SE" I just figured it was yet another bizarre computer system related query.  Even though it has been closed as story based, I'd honestly recommend editing to remove the jabs. This is Worldbuilding.  We're better than that, I hope, though I do understand the emotion behind the action!

Comment: We've taken stabs at just about everybody at some point round here. Once the context is in the past and the air has cleared, why should SE be immune from that?

Comment: @Separatrix I agree.  Things are a little fresh at the moment, in a few months+ I would probably approach it totally differently.

Comment: "A jab at SE" isn't one of the close reasons. What actual question rule is it breaking?

Comment: @TheAnathema rude/not nice, for example.